# PHP Outputting results based on greater than/less than from JSON

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to get this script to output results based on a greater than/less than script. When I run this script all it does it output the first line in the text file. Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

```
<?php
$lines     = file('unique.txt'); // Reads the file with the list of user numbers
$timestamp = time(); // Defines time for below renaming

foreach ($lines as $usernumber) { // Loops line by line
    $link = 'http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v2/?&steamids=' . $usernumber . '&format=json';
    $json = file_get_contents($link); // Reads link (this ^)
    $data = json_decode($json); // Defines decode as json
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $profiles = array(); //init array so we can use $profiles[] later
        foreach ($data->response->players as $player) { // Loop thrugh all the players
            $player2 = $player->backpack_value;
            if ($player2 < 9999999) { // Check the backpack_value
                $profiles[] = $player; // Assign the required players to a new array

                var_dump($profiles); // Dump the array to browser for debugning
                $fh = fopen("final." . $timestamp . ".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file"); // Opens final.txt to write in
                fwrite($fh, $usernumber); // Writes the parsed results to final.txt
            } //closes if $playtime

        } //closes foreach $data
    } //closes if !empty
    else {
        echo $data;
    }
} //closes foreach $lines

?>
```

Unique.txt contains

```
76561197992831594
76561197992707820
76561197992146126
76561197992694522
76561197992707820
76561197992831594
```

JSON Example

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1369685515,
        "players": {
            "0": {
                "steamid": "76561197992831594",
                "success": 1,
                "backpack_value": 47.97,
                "backpack_update": 1369683750,
                "name": "WesFox13",
                "notifications": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably not the issue but it would be better if you moved the `$fh = fopen("final." . $timestamp . ".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file"); // Opens final.txt to write in' to outside of the foreach (like the line before would be good. Now you are reopening the file every time you find a match.

Comment: Sounds good, I moved it in my personal script, for now I will leave it in on this one. Still trying to find where I went wrong...

Comment: if it just echoes out $data again, the obviously the json_decode failed. use `json_last_error()` and `var_dump($json)` to see what happened. Most likely that server is not returning valid json, or returning something that isn't json at all (e.g. an anti-scraper/ToS violation notice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay There is two fundamental problems.

1. The fopen call needs to move outside of the loop.
2. the file call has an annoying habit of keeping the trailing newline. When you are building up your url you should use  `trim($usernumber)` to get rid of it.

Here is an update with those two things in place.

```
<?php
$lines     = file('unique.txt'); // Reads the file with the list of user numbers
$timestamp = time(); // Defines time for below renaming

$fh = fopen("final." . $timestamp . ".txt", 'a') or die("can't open file"); // Opens final.txt to write in
foreach ($lines as $usernumber) { // Loops line by line
    $link = 'http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v2/?&steamids=' . trim($usernumber) . '&format=json';
    $json = file_get_contents($link); // Reads link (this ^)
    $data = json_decode($json); // Defines decode as json
    print_r($json);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $profiles = array(); //init array so we can use $profiles[] later
        foreach ($data->response->players as $player) { // Loop thrugh all the players
            $player2 = $player->backpack_value;
            if ($player2 < 9999999) { // Check the backpack_value
                $profiles[] = $player; // Assign the required players to a new array

                var_dump($profiles); // Dump the array to browser for debugning
                fwrite($fh, $usernumber); // Writes the parsed results to final.txt
            } //closes if $playtime

        } //closes foreach $data
    } //closes if !empty
    else {
        echo $data;
    }
} //closes foreach $lines
```

Comment: I will be studying this closely to see what I did wrong, thanks a TON for this, it really helped!

Comment: not a problem... the big one was the trim then building the url (where you are assigning the link) to debug these kind of issues in the future it's a good idea to use echo and die liberally to make sure you are both sending and receiving what you intend

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with CURL and it works too.

The code:

```
$lines = array('76561197992831594','76561197992707820','76561197992146126');
    $timestamp = time(); // Defines time for below renaming

    foreach ($lines as $usernumber) { // Loops line by line
        $link = 'http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v2/?&steamids=' . $usernumber . '&format=json';
        $json = curl_download($link); // Reads link (this ^)
        $data = json_decode($json); // Defines decode as json
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $profiles = array(); //init array so we can use $profiles[] later
            foreach ($data->response->players as $player) { // Loop thrugh all the players
                $player2 = $player->backpack_value;
                if ($player2 < 9999999) { // Check the backpack_value
                    $profiles[] = $player; // Assign the required players to a new array

                    var_dump($profiles); // Dump the array to browser for debugning
                     file_put_contents("final." . $timestamp . ".txt", $usernumber);
                } //closes if $playtime

            } //closes foreach $data
        } //closes if !empty
        else {
            echo $data;
        }
    }
```

curl download function:

```
function curl_download($Url){

// is cURL installed yet?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Now set some options (most are optional)

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

// Set a referer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.pl");

// User agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla Firefox/1.0");

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#102 (6) { ["steamid"]=> string(17) "76561197992831594" ["success"]=> int(1) ["backpack_value"]=> float(47.97) ["backpack_update"]=> int(1369683750) ["name"]=> string(8) "WesFox13" ["notifications"]=> int(0) } } array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#106 (6) { ["steamid"]=> string(17) "76561197992707820" ["success"]=> int(1) ["backpack_value"]=> float(59.78) ["backpack_update"]=> int(1369689171) ["name"]=> string(10) "Alexsutton" ["notifications"]=> int(0) } } array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#98 (6) { ["steamid"]=> string(17) "76561197992146126" ["success"]=> int(1) ["backpack_value"]=> float(36181.59) ["backpack_update"]=> int(1369689000) ["name"]=> string(25) ":HIT: Bobo the Monkey Boy" ["notifications"]=> int(0) } }
```

My suggestion to you is to use CURL when you want to download something from Web. Moreover use **file_get_contents()** and **file_put_contents()** syntax is short and they do the same and they are easier to use.

Comment: I will also be examining this. I hear CURL is what I should be using anways!